# Can this be solved with a line sweep algorithm in O(n)?

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry, intersection, segment

In this problem we are given n horizontal segments in the plane, find in O(n) time a line that intersects all the segments and has the largest possible slope, or determine that there is no such line.

I thought about finding all possible lines by having an inequality solving it and getting all possible line equations and then finding the one with the biggest slope however I can't find the solution is related to anything we learned in computational geometry
Can anyone give me a hint or mention any related subject in computational geometry that could help

Comment: A line sweep requires a preliminary sort. Forget the O(n) bound.

Answer (score 1):

No, this problem can't be solved by the line sweep algorithm in linear time - please see the @YvesDaoust comment. However, it can be solved in linear time by another method - please see below.

Your intent to describe intersections between `n` segments and the stabbing line **by inequalities** was correct, however you could go further and reduce your problem to a linear programming (LP) problem with two variables and `2*n` constraints.

Let's denote parameters of a segment `i` by three numbers - `xMin(i)`, `xMax(i)` and `y(i)`. The stabbing line will be described by equation `y = a*x + b`. This line must intersect the segment `i`, so for each such segment we have two inequalities, guaranteeing the intersection:

```
a*xMin(i) + b <= y(i)
a*xMax(i) + b >= y(i)
```

So, you need to maximize the slope `a` subject to `2*n` constraints above, and this is a well known fixed-dimension LP problem with two variables `a` and `b`. According to [this paper](http://theory.stanford.edu/%7Emegiddo/pdf/lplin.pdf) by Nimrod Megiddo, LP problems with `n` constraints and **fixed** (non-depending on the `n`) number of variables can be solved in `O(n)` time.

Answer (score 0):

As comments suggested line sweep algorithm is slower than `O(n)` so **the answer is NO** however simple `O(n)` approach is still possible for example like this:

1. **find BBOX of your intersection line**

   so You are searching for `x0,y0,x1,y1` coordinates of "inscribed" rectangle crossing the interior of all lines (aqua rectangle). This can be done in `O(n)`

   [image: BBOX]

   So search all lines and get:

   ```
   y0 = min(y)
   y1 = max(y)
   x0 = max(left_x)
   x1 = min(righ_x)
   ```

   where `left_x<right_x` are the two `x` coordinates of each line.
2. **construct your line**

   In case the `x0>x1` there is **no such line possible**.

   For **smallest slope** simply use one of the diagonals of the BBOX:

   ```
   Line(x0,y0,x1,y1)
   Line(x0,y1,x1,y0)
   ```

   [image: diagonal]

   which depends on your coordinate system (points might be even reversed)...

   The **biggest slope** is vertical line so you can use any `x` inside `<x0,x1>` interval for example

   ```
   Line(x0,y0,x0,y1)
   ```

   [image: vertical line]

Comment: This approach won't cover all possible cases - the rectangular bounding box might not exist, however a stabbing line with slope < 90 might exist.

Comment: @HEKTO hmm good point +1 ... for the non rectangular BBOX case should be searched for min and max slope (atan2) instead of min and max x ad once they cross each other handle as non solvable ... however that would most likely be slower than `O(n)` (as also the start point range is needed) unless some nasty trick I do not see now is used ...